# Symbol for information icon in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, frontend

Is there any HTML entity code for info icon ?
HTML Entity for info symbol
I want to symbol for info icon in html page I have tried many entity symbol but not working
i am using html 5 version

`<h2>#  &#x1F6</h2>`

Comment: Did  you check in this table: [link]https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references which is referenced by [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity If you can't see the shape you want try an icon font like fontawesome which has several types of info and question icons.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `&#9432;`, and this: ⓘ is what it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```html
<h2>&#8505;</h2>
```